# Analyzing the log file based on regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, input, permissions, get

I am trying to read the log file and pull out the statistical data from the file.

I tried with PHP, i used Ubuntu commands to do the process, now i am struck to declare the variable which can hold my input file from the path and provide the date to the rest of the code from the variable name.

```php
<?php

$input = file_get_contents("data.log");

$get = shell_exec("grep -c "GET" $input");

echo "$get";

?>
```

Comment: you can just do `shell_exec('grep -c "GET" path/to/data.log');` right ?

Comment: Firstly... Your string inside the function is in single quotes and therefore `$input` is literal and not outputting the actual data.

Comment: but i used same path in multiple places, so i need to declare it in global and use it in the cade

Comment: i used double quotes as well, still not working

Comment: Use manual regex from PHP maybe on the obtained string from file_get_contents() ?

Comment: Also, you can't put a file resource in a string concatenation as is. Also, if you are using the `w` flag, the file is always empty.

Comment: after replacing with r also its not working

Comment: `$input` is now your file contents. You can get whatever you want from it: `preg_match_all('/\d+/', $input, $matches); print_r($matches[0]);` will show all numbers. What do you need?